# Compute vertical scroll range and offset for recycler view with different view types

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fastscroll

My question if pretty clear. I'm trying to add fast scroll for recycler view with different view types and for that I need to calculate vertical scroll range and offset. I have 6 view types with height that depend on content. I'm using GridLayoutManager and its implementation of the methods:

- computeVerticalScrollRange
- computeVerticalScrollOffset

are not applicable for rv with different view types.

Could someone help me with this please?

Comment: Can't both view types has the same size?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I have 6 view types, all of them have different height that depends on content

Comment: Why you say that those methods are not applicable for different viewtypes?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos It gives approximate scroll range based on items count and their height and when different view type comes up on the screen it changes its value.

Comment: can't you override those and calculate yourself?

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos yeah, this is what I want to do. but I can't find solution for doing this for now.

Comment: Take a look into the GridLayoutManager to see how it wraps columns, this can be a start